# Aligning rasters in rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I am struggling with a task that seems like it should be quite simple. I have two rasters with the same size, resolution, CSR, but slightly different bounds. I need to perform a fairly simple calculation across, which requires that I align the two rasters. If I understand correctly, I need to perform some sort of reprojection on one of the rasters to align it with the other.

I see that there is function that provides a transform from the bounds, rasterio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, width, height), which seems like it would be the easiest way to go about this. Based on what I've found online, it seems like I need to do something like following to define and then apply the appropriate transform:

```
with rasterio.open('raster_1.tif') as src:
    west, south, east, north = src.bounds
    width = src.width'
    height = src.height
    transform = from_bounds(west, south, east, north, width, height)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({

        'crs': src.crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height})


    with rasterio.open('raster_2.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        reproject(
            source=rasterio.band(src, 1),
            destination=rasterio.band(dst, 1),
            src_transform=src.transform,
            src_crs=src.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=src.crs,
            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

When I check the bounds on the second raster, I see that it does indeed now line up with the first, except it seems that I have totally changed all of the data in raster. What have done wrong here?

Comment: If both rasters are already correctly georeferenced then it sounds like you just need to read the same geographic area from each of them.  You could do this with a [windowed read](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html), creating a single [window from bounds](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.from_bounds) then reading that window from each raster

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! I'm getting the message that the window from bounds function requires a transform object to calculate the window. What sort of transform do I need if I don't actually want to warp the raster?

Comment: You need two windows (with same bounds), one per raster. You use each rasters `dataset.transform` as the transform for thw windpw from bounds function..